# VBA not changing all dates from text format to date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am having a problem for a long time now.. I have been trying to find some differences between dates and print the result in minutes. However, my problem is that even if I have added a line of code to convert the cell format to date format dd/mm/yyyy, it doesnt apply for the cells, but only for a part of them. Also, for some, it applies, but it creates the date format mm/dd/yyyy. I really dont what to do. These dates are vlookups from another sheet. So, I even wrote a line of code to transform them in their original sheets too. So , it total, just to be sure, I am making two convertions. My code is given below! please help me :)

```
Sheets("TMS").Select
lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("K2:K" & lastrow)
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("K2:K" & lastrow)) Then
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
    End If
End With
Sheets("TheTracker").Select
lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("AO2:AO" & lastrow)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,TMS!B:K,10,FALSE)"
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Why `.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"`???

Comment: I need it to have this format.. I need the hours and the minutes too

Comment: Please, note you say you want `dd/mm/yyyy` but your code has `.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"`. Why doesn't it contains `.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to refer better to the Ranges, without using `Select`, refering to the worksheet that you need, and disregarding the `hh:mm`. Something like this may work probably:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("TMS")
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("K2:K" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    End With

    With Worksheets("TheTracker")
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("AO2:AO" & lastRow)
            .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,TMS!B:K,10,FALSE)"
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            .value = .value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed! When I go to the date and check format as general, it still shows the date, not a number, so its still a text

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas try adding somewhere `.Range("K2:K" & lastRow).value = .Range("K2:K" & lastRow).value`. Or start recording a macro, until you don't get what you need.

Comment: well still nothing :( half the dates are in date format and half the dates are in text format. Also,half of the dates that are in date format are in mm/dd/yyyy and the other half dd/mm/yyyy. I believe that there is an error with the type of code I am using. Possibly there will be a code instead of .NumberFormat that could do the job..

Comment: Try rewriting the dates like this `11-Jan-2017` in Excel. Then run it again.

Comment: well the problem is that the value (the date) that I vlookup in the "TMS" sheet is coming from a platform.. So , I need to work with this format as it needs to be automated.

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - just give it a try. If it works, you know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If a date format is applied to only a few of the cells, it looks like a disjoint of your computer's regional settings and the date format.

If you computer is set to show dates as DMY, then a date like

- `1/1/2017` will be a real date - January 1
- `12/7/2017` will be a real date - July 12
- `13/7/2017` will be a real date - July 13

But

- `7/13/2017` will not be a date, because the order of day and month are wrong.

The same goes for computers with regional settings to show dates as MDY, popular in the US.

- `1/1/2017` will be a real date - January 1
- `12/7/2017` will be a real date - December 7
- `13/7/2017` will not be a real date - because there is no 13th month.

So, check what format the source data is displayed in: DMY or MDY?

Then adjust your VBA routine to pull the month and the day according to your computer's regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Dates as Text and Excel will not look at them as a date, you can try something like this.

```
Columns("K:K").Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("K1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that the data came from a CSV file that you `OPEN`'d.

If that is the case, you are better off doing an `IMPORT` (usually on the `DATA` ribbon).

When you do this, the `Text Import Wizard` will open and you will be able to specify the date format of the incoming data.

Excel will then convert all of these dates to **real** dates, and you will be able to apply the number format.  This `IMPORT` process can be automated through VBA if necessary.